# I can't destroy blocks in Minecraft Creative Mode (singleplayer)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just logged in to Minecraft after maybe 8-9 months at the most. When I first logged in, I tried to switch between modes but I forgot how, so I looked for it and it said to press <kbd>F1</kbd>. Before I did I could destroy and place blocks, but now I can't destroy them! Is this common, and does anyone know how to fix it?
And btw, whenever I go onto a bare hand to destroy something, it just goes back to the first item in my inventory.

Answer (score 2):

### **First things first.**

F1 makes your Minecraft become into like a Camera Mode. It removes your inventory and hand that you can see again if you press F1 again.

### **Next.**

If you cannot destroy blocks, either you are holding a sword, or you are in Adventure Mode.

You can change back by executing the command (pre 1.13):

```
/gamemode 1
```

Edit: The new command post 1.13 is:

```
/gamemode creative
```

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/gamemode creative`

Answer (score 0):

Try not to keep a sword in your hand while trying to break blocks,because they won't. Attack with your empty hand or with another object.

Answer (score -1):

You could be in spectator mode or adventure mode. You should be able to go into creative mode by using /gamemode 1 on a world with cheats

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/gamemode creative`