# why cant i break blocks in Minecraft but still kill animals?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

see I am in creative mode and tried doing the mouse button 1 attack but that still didn't work, I am in creative mode playing with a friend, well at least trying. so I am in multi player, I also kicked my friend outta the game to see if it would work with just me but it didn't. And also i tried the command to creative. it did nothing because I was in creative already
so if someone could help me that would be great!
otherwise ill just wind up deleteing the world.

Comment: Do you own this minecraft world?

Comment: yes i created it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't destroy blocks in minecraft creative mode (single)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/226320/i-cant-destroy-blocks-in-minecraft-creative-mode-single)

Comment: acctually no because when i go into my world, i Am creative mode and i dont have a sword in my hand ive done the commands thing and breaking blocks just dosent work besides killing animals

Comment: I think we should reopen this because the solution in that thread isn’t working, and this has an additional issue along with it

Comment: @Penguin Duplicates are judged on the basis of questions, not the answers and whether or not they're helpful. As long as this question isn't differentiated from the other, it will be considered a duplicate.

Comment: @Joachim but this has an additional issue with it, the problem of not being able to punch mobs. Isn't that a different question entirely?

Comment: @Penguin That is assuming the poster of the older question didn't have that problem. I also don't see any indication of the OP being able to punch mobs; where do you see that?

Comment: @Joachim but it doesn't seem that he says that he can't hit mobs, also it says he keeps getting reset to the first hotbar slot. Don't these seem like two separate issues that have one thing in common? The issue with the other person is that it seems he was in adventure mode, but that wouldn't explain this because this person cannot hit mobs. The other person can hit mobs since they were only in F1 and adventure mode.

Comment: i can hit mobs, i just cant do anything else but i don't see that problem because I've done everything to try and fix it. I think it just one of Minecraft's glitches and it cant necessarily be fixed, So I'm going to delete the world.  thanks tho for trying to help u guys.